# Swapping bits in a byte

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I'm trying to create a function that changes the bits of a given input byte, c1, depending on the least significant bits of another byte, called the key.

If key has any 1's in its least significant bits, then the bits of c1 need to be swapped according to its corresponding mirror bit positions.

So lets say for example,

key = 0110 1010, we only care about 1010 as its the least significant bit.

c1 = 0010 1011

According to 1010, we need to swap the 1st position with 6th, and 3rd position with 4th in c1.

c1 should end up being 0111 0001.

This is what I have gotten done so far:

```
unsigned char swapBits(unsigned char c1, unsigned char key){
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            key = (key >> i);
            if(key & 1){
               /* swap bits here */
            }
    }
    return c1;
}
```

How would I achieve this?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What exactly does the result need to be?

Comment: Well in this example, the result is expected to be 0111 0001.

Comment: Further explanation is required.

Comment: usage of the word "nibble" in the description of this problem, would likely have made it both shorter and more understandable.

Comment: 0 = (least significant) bit, 1010 = (least significant) nibble, 01101010 = byte.

Comment: `According to 1010, we need to swap the 1st position with 6th, and 3rd position with 4th in c1.` This doesn't make any sense to me, you have to clarify what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdint>    // uint8_t
#include <limits.h>  // CHAR_BIT

uint8_t furtle(uint8_t val, uint8_t key) 
{
    uint8_t mask_lo = 0x01;                  // init masks at LS and MS bits
    uint8_t mask_hi = mask_lo << (CHAR_BIT - 1);
    for (int b = 0; b < CHAR_BIT / 2; ++b)
    {
        if (key & mask_lo)                   // if bit b is set in val
        {
            uint8_t b_lo = val & mask_lo;    // get corresponding low/high bits
            uint8_t b_hi = val & mask_hi;    // and swap them
            val = (val & ~mask_lo) | (b_hi >> (CHAR_BIT - b * 2 - 1));
            val = (val & ~mask_hi) | (b_lo << (CHAR_BIT - b * 2 - 1));
        }
        mask_lo <<= 1;                       // shift masks
        mask_hi >>= 1;
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I sorta get it now. Is uint8_t equivalent to unsigned char? Your variables are just kinda hard to follow.

Comment: `uint8_t` is defined in `<stdint.h>` - it's typically just `unsigned char` but strictly speaking it's an unsigned int of at least 8 bits in size.

Answer (score -2):

You may insert all the bits into an array then swap the elements.

Finally, read all the elements as output or use string.concat  function to add thee elements into a string.

Comment: Not very helpful answer, especially as the question is tagged as `C`.